# Issue with selecting only specific Links with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I want to add a "visited" data-attribute to specific links to show visitors which pages the have already visited. I'm using the script by [Joel](http://joelcalifa.com/blog/revisiting-visited/) but I can't make it only select specific links (say checking for specific ID or CLASS).

I already tried using `if(links[i].idName=="showcase")` to select links in my HTML code that have `id="showcase"` but it does not work.

Full code:

```
localStorage.setItem('visited-'+window.location.pathname,true);
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0;i<links.length;i++) {   
    if(links[i].idName=="showcase") {
        var link = links[i];
        if (link.host == window.location.host
        && localStorage.getItem('visited-' + link.pathname)) {
           link.dataset.visited = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

First, IDs should be unique. If you need multiple elements to have the same selector, use a class instead:

```
<a href="/home">Not affected</a>
<a href="/my-super-project" class="showcase">Affected</a>
<a href="/my-super-project2" class="showcase">Affected</a>
```

#### JS

Then, if you only want to get your `.showcase` links, instead of doing `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, you could do this to select only the ones you want:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('showcase');
```

And here is your final code:

```
localStorage.setItem('visited-' + window.location.pathname, true);

var links = document.getElementsByClassName('showcase');
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++) {   
  var link = links[i];
  if(link.host == window.location.host && localStorage.getItem('visited-' + link.pathname)) {
     link.dataset.visited = true;
  }
}
```

#### CSS

Since the above code will add a `data-visited` attribute to your links, you can use that in your styles:

```
a[data-visited] {
  color: green;
}
```

> **Note:** If you notice that your styles don't work, you could make the selector more precise :
>
> ```
> .main a.showcase[data-visited] {
>   color: green;
> }
> ```
>
> ... or add an `!important` flag to your rules:
>
> ```
> a.showcase[data-visited] {
>   color: green !important;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @blex. I actually had already tried that before but without any success...